# Errors using ompi-server to connect independently started processes

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I'm new to Open MPI and trying to figure it out. I want to be able to have a process started later to connect to a previously started process possible running on another node through an ompi-server, but I keep getting errors from the client. After a few hours of searching for an answer, I'm finally asking.

```
ompi-server --no-daemonize -d -r +
[kurenai:15711] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-barronj@kurenai_0/30031/0/0
[kurenai:15711] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-barronj@kurenai_0/30031/0
[kurenai:15711] top: openmpi-sessions-barronj@kurenai_0
[kurenai:15711] tmp: /tmp
[kurenai:15711] sess_dir_cleanup: job session dir does not exist
[kurenai:15711] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-barronj@kurenai_0/30031/0/0
[kurenai:15711] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-barronj@kurenai_0/30031/0
[kurenai:15711] top: openmpi-sessions-barronj@kurenai_0
[kurenai:15711] tmp: /tmp
1968111616.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:55602
[kurenai:15711] [[30031,0],0] orte-server: up and running!
```

Afterwards, I run the server.

```
mpirun -np 1 --hostfile ~/mpi-hosts --ompi-server "1968111616.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:55602" /home/barronj/ompi_test/port_server
port = 1982005248.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:38916+1982005249.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:41605:300
```

Here is the relevant code that the server runs.

```
try {
    MPI::Open_port(MPI::INFO_NULL, port);
} catch (MPI::Exception e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server open port error (%d): %s\n", e.Get_error_code(), e.Get_error_string());
    MPI::Finalize();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

MPI::Info info = MPI::Info::Create();
info.Set("ompi_global_scope", "true");

try {
    MPI::Publish_name("test_service", info, port);
} catch (MPI::Exception e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server service publish error (%d): %s\n", e.Get_error_code(), e.Get_error_string());
    info.Free();
    MPI::Close_port(port);
    MPI::Finalize();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

info.Free();

printf("port = %s\n", port);

try {
    intercomm = MPI::COMM_SELF.Accept(port, MPI::INFO_NULL, 0);
} catch (MPI::Exception e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server accept error (%d): %s\n", e.Get_error_code(), e.Get_error_string());
    MPI::Unpublish_name("test_service", MPI::INFO_NULL, port);
    MPI::Close_port(port);
    MPI::Finalize();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

On another node, I run the client and get an error.

```
mpirun -np 1 --hostfile ~/mpi-hosts --ompi-server "1968111616.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:55602" /home/barronj/ompi_test/port_client
barronj@kurenai's password:
Client found test_service on port, 1982005248.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:38916+1982005249.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:41605:300
[athena:07039] [[28058,0],0]-[[30243,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_peer_send_handler: invalid connection state (6) on socket 19
```

As can be seen, the service and port were found. But connecting causes an error. Here is the relevant client code.

```
try {
    MPI::Lookup_name("test_service", MPI_INFO_NULL, port);
} catch (MPI::Exception e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Service lookup error (%d): %s\n", e.Get_error_code(), e.Get_error_string());
    MPI::Finalize();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

printf("Client found test_service on port, %s\n", port);

try {
    intercomm = MPI::COMM_SELF.Connect(port, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0);
} catch (MPI::Exception e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Client connect error (%d): %s\n", e.Get_error_code(), e.Get_error_string());
    MPI::Finalize();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

As I'm new, I don't fully understand this stuff yet. I've tried using MPI::COMM_WORLD. That doesn't fix it.

I'm not sure if this is related, but I tried to add the wait for server option.

```
mpirun -np 1 --hostfile ~/mpi-hosts --ompi-server "1968111616.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:55602" --wait-for-server /home/barronj/ompi_test/port_client
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was instructed to wait for the requested ompi-server, but was unable to
establish contact with the server during the specified wait time:

Server uri:  1968111616.0;tcp://192.168.1.219:55602
Timeout time: 10

Error received: Not supported

Please check to ensure that the requested server matches the actual server
information, and that the server is in operation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adding this option to the server does the same thing.

I have also tried using --ompi-server with a file instead of a copy-paste. This only produces the same problems.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.